# Unable to get value in <input> field using this.val() or this.attr('value')

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get values of a number of ***input*** fields in a ***fieldset*** tag. But the *$(this).val()* or *$(this).attr('value')* is returning the old value of the field instead of the new value updated by the user. Below is the html code:

```
<fieldset id="fieldset_id">             
    <div class="form-item">
        <input type="text" input_id="1" value="aaa_1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <input type="text" input_id="2" value="aaa_2">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

and below is the code which is executed after the user updates the input field and presses the "**save**" button:

```
$('#fieldset_id').find("input").each(function(){
    idsArray.push($(this).attr('input_id'));
    newValues.push($(this).val());
});
```

Now, here is the use case:

1. The current values of the input fields are **aaa_1** and **aaa_2** respectively.
2. The user updates the value of **aaa_1** to **aaa_111** and presses the **save** button.
3. On pressing the **save** button, the code above is executed.

The values in *newValues* array are **aaa_1** and **aaa_2** instead of **aaa_111** and **aaa_2**.

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nf469/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear array before pushing values.

Write:

```
idsArray = newValues = [];
$('#fieldset_id').find("input").each(function(){
    idsArray.push($(this).attr('input_id'));
    newValues.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: I am declaring arrays like this:
 var idsArray= new Array();
 var newValues= new Array();
I assume this is the same as suggested by you?

Comment: @rsharma `var categoryIds = new Array();` declares array, whereas `idsArray = newValues = [];` clears existing arrays.

Comment: tried it still no luck.
Anyways, thank you for explaining the difference.

Comment: @rsharma can you post fiddle?

Comment: Yes its working on fiddle. But its not working in my application.Its a spring-MVC based app and the view in which these input fields are present is being returned by a controller and being replaced using an ajax call. Can this issue be because of the view being replaced at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

**Your Arrays are not defined,**

define it like this,

```
var idsArray = [], newValues= [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<form id="fieldset_id">             
    <div class="form-item">
        <input type="text" input_id="1" value="aaa_1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <input type="text" input_id="2" value="aaa_2"/>
    </div>
    <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

Script

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
var idsArray = [], newValues= [];
$('#fieldset_id').find("input").each(function(){
    idsArray.push($(this).attr('input_id'));
    newValues.push($(this).val());
    console.log(idsArray, newValues)
});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nf469/2/)

Comment: tried initializing arrays using var idsArray = [], newValues= [];
Still not working.

Comment: its working see fiddle console it will display with new updated values

Comment: Yes its working on fiddle. But its not working in my application.Its a spring-MVC based app and the view in which these input fields are present is being returned by a controller and being replaced using an ajax call. Can this issue be because of the view being replaced at run-time>